# PowerShell Webrequest POST for PowerShell 2.0

Tags: post, powershell-2.0

How can I modify this snippet code for PowerShell version 2.0 on Windows 7?

```
$path = "myfolder/file.txt"
$body = "file=$(Get-Content $path | Out-String)"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http//mywebsite" -Method POST -Body $body`
```

I tried this but cannot run on PowerShell version 2.0.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Check for the PS version in windows 7 and run the powershell ISE in adminstrator mode. Meanwhile what error you are getting , need more info on problem statement

Comment: powershell version is 2.0 and regarding  the error: the term"Invoke.Webrequest' is not recognized as the name of cmdlet,function,script file ecc

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy/paste the full error message. Do not paraphrase. Do not type from memory.

Comment: i got this error: Invoke-WebRequest : The term 'Invoke-WebRequest' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program
. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:18
+ Invoke-WebRequest <<<<  -uri "http://example.com"   -method POST -body $body
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Invoke-WebRequest:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoke-webRequest is present in PowerShell v3.0 [ref - [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6)

There are two solution to solve the problem, one you can update the powershell version to 3 or above ,
else use following cmdlet to perform WebRequest.

```
$WebRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://url")
$WebRequest.Method = "GET"
$WebRequest.ContentType = "application/json"
$Response = $WebRequest.GetResponse()
$ResponseStream = $Response.GetResponseStream()
$ReadStream = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $ResponseStream
$Data=$ReadStream.ReadToEnd()
```

Comment: ok this works for the method "GET" and for the method "POST"?

Comment: Yes, please change the $WebRequest.Method ="POST" and pass required header too in order to work, Please accept the answer if it solve the problem.

Comment: already changed and is working now!thank you for your help Vinod!